# Difference between GCC arm options necessary when cross-compiling and when compiling directly on target?

Tags: c++, arm, g++, cross-compiling

I'm have created a c++ app and want to compile it for debian jessie 8.0 armbian target of a cubietruck board (ARM® Cortex™-A7 Dual-Core).
The `- cat /proc/cpuinfo` gives :

```
Processor       : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
processor       : 0
BogoMIPS        : 956.30

processor       : 1
BogoMIPS        : 959.75

Features        : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xc07
CPU revision    : 4

Hardware        : sun7i
Revision        : 0000
Serial          : 1651668805c0e142
Chipid          : 16516688-80515475-52574848-05c0e142
```

and the `- dpkg --print-architecture`

```
armhf
```

I have concluded that the related arm gcc option for cross compilation  I need are:

```
--with-abi=aapcs-linux  (-mabi)
--with-cpu=cortex-a7  (-mcpu)
--with-tune=cortex-a7 (-mtune)
--with-mode=arm/thumb  (-marm  -mthumb)
--with-fpu=neon-vfpv4  (-mfpu)
--with-float=hard
```

If I want to build the same source directly on board is the option `-march=native` (if it is supported) sufficient or do I need any of the above flags as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find what flags `-march=native` activates use `gcc -march=native -Q --help=target`.

This is the output in my board (Pine64 - Cortex A53 with Linux 64 bits):

```
debian@pine64:~$ gcc -march=native -Q --help=target
The following options are target specific:
    -mabi=ABI                           lp64
    -march=ARCH                         native
    -mbig-endian                        [disabled]
    -mbionic                            [disabled]
    -mcmodel=                           small
    -mcpu=CPU                           
    -mfix-cortex-a53-835769             [enabled]
    -mgeneral-regs-only                 [disabled]
    -mglibc                             [enabled]
    -mlittle-endian                     [enabled]
    -mlra                               [enabled]
    -momit-leaf-frame-pointer           [enabled]
    -mstrict-align                      [disabled]
    -mtls-dialect=                      desc
    -mtune=CPU                          
    -muclibc                            [disabled]
    ....
    [Omitted output]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just one question. When one compile on the targer board is there any difference to compile just with g++ or with g++ -march=native or the have the same effect ?

Comment: In principle yes, however, the GCC website says:
-march=native causes the compiler to auto-detect the architecture of the build computer. At present, this feature is only supported on GNU/Linux, and not all architectures are recognized. If the auto-detect is unsuccessful the option has no effect.
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html

Comment: Is there a way (command, or message) to find out whether auto-detect is unsuccessful ?

Comment: As far as I know, there is nothing to tell you. However, if you compile using the `-g` flag, then you can use `strings` to get the flags, but I am not 100% on this, it worked on my board.

$strings your_binary | grep =
But I am not sure if this is just the command used.